# Could not find developer disk image

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7, ios9.2

I am using **xcode 7.1** (7B91b). I connected my iPad OS version **9.2** to my macbook, then, I selected my iPad in xcode & run my iOS project. But xcode pops up an error "**Could not find Developer Disk Image**".

[image]

How to get rid of this problem & having my project running on my iPad?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to update XCode - most times I got this error was when I updated device but didn't update XCode.

My xcode is 7.2 for 9.2 iOS.